# realm js: Access to invalidated Results objects

Tags: realm, realm-js

I use realm inside my React native application a try to query list of objects from realm db.

```
function* loadPlaces() {
    let realm;
    try {
        const filter = yield select(getFilter);
        realm = yield call(Realm.open, {schema: [PlaceSchema]});
        let places = realm.objects(PlaceSchema.name);
        if (filter.search) {
            places = places.filtered("name CONTAINS $0", filter.search);
        }
        switch (filter.sort) {
            case Sort.BY_NAME:
                places = places.sorted('name');
                break;
        }
        yield put(loadPlacesSucceed(places));
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e.message);
    } finally {
        if (realm) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

After that I use resulted data in flatlist:

```
<FlatList
        data={this.props.items}
        keyExtractor={(item) => '' + item.id}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
            <PlaceItem item={item} onClick={(item) => this._onItemClicked(item)}/>}/>
```

And receive error:

> Access to invalidated Results objects.

If i remove realm.close() error disapear, but I need to close realm after query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why do you think you need to close Realm after a query? If you close your Realm, you lose access to all auto-updating collections, such as `Results`, so you shouldn't close your Realm as long as you need access to a specific `Results` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did the same thing. I open Realm with all schemas, that I need for my app and not close it at all.

Answer (score 5):

It happens because as soon as the `realm` is closed, all access to data, which in current case is `Results`, is lost.

However as mentioned by OP `"not close it at all"` is not a good approach. Ideally it should be closed. You can see the [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest#introduction) says,

> // Remember to close the realm when finished.

So what you can basically do is, open `realm` in `componentDidMount` and close it in `componentWillUnmount`.

Like,

```
componentDidMount() {
    Realm.open({
        schema: [{ name: 'SCHEMA_NAME', properties: { name: 'string' } }]
    }).then(realm => {
        this.setState({ realm });
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    // Close the realm if there is one open.
    const { realm } = this.state;
    if (realm !== null && !realm.isClosed) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```